How can I execute Xbox 360 console commands externally (in Xenia environment) using C++?
I been working on a DX mod menu for an xbox 360 game, but its running in the Xenia environment. On Xbox, all I had to do was use the JRPC CallVoid function. so it would be Kewi.CallVoid(0x8263CB10, "cutscene_play"), but I'm having trouble getting it to work on the Xenia environment. Xenia address would be 0x18263CB10. on Xbox Kewi.CallVoid(0x8263CB10, "cutscene_play") would send and execute command with no further instructions. The menu is external.
Here's an attempt I made that didn't work.
typedef void(__fastcall* ConsoleCommandT)(...);

void CallVoid(HANDLE hProcess, uint64_t Address, const std::vector<uint64_t>& Arguments)
{
    HANDLE remoteThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, nullptr, 0,
        (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)Address, nullptr, 0, nullptr);

    if (remoteThread == nullptr) {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("Failed to create remote thread in the target process."), _T("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    else {
        WaitForSingleObject(remoteThread, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(remoteThread);
    }
}

void ExecuteConsoleCommand()
{
    DWORD processId = GetProcessIdByName(L"xenia_canary.exe");

    if (processId != 0) {
        HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, processId);
        if (hProcess != NULL) {
            uintptr_t consoleCommandFunctionAddress = 0x18263CB10;
            const char* command = "cutscene_play";
            SIZE_T bytesWritten = 0;

            void* remoteMemory = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, nullptr, strlen(command) + 1, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
            if (remoteMemory == nullptr) {
                MessageBox(NULL, _T("Failed to allocate memory in the target process."), _T("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
                CloseHandle(hProcess);
                return;
            }

            BOOL success = WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, remoteMemory, command, strlen(command) + 1, &bytesWritten);

            if (!success || bytesWritten != strlen(command) + 1) {
                MessageBox(NULL, _T("Failed to write console command to memory."), _T("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
                VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, remoteMemory, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
                CloseHandle(hProcess);
                return;
            }

            HANDLE remoteThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, nullptr, 0,
                (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)consoleCommandFunctionAddress, remoteMemory, 0, nullptr);

            if (remoteThread == nullptr) {
                MessageBox(NULL, _T("Failed to create remote thread in the target process."), _T("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
            }
            else {
                WaitForSingleObject(remoteThread, INFINITE);
                CloseHandle(remoteThread);
            }

            VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, remoteMemory, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
            CloseHandle(hProcess);
        }
        else {
            MessageBox(NULL, _T("Failed to open process."), _T("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        }
    }
    else {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("Xenia process not found."), _T("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    }
}

This just results in enter image description here.
Unhandled Exception in Xenia

Exception encountered!
Build: netplay_canary_experimental@7a8c2b258 on Aug 4 2024
Exception address: 0x8263CB10
Stackpointer: 0xD3AEAFFF8
Instruction pointer: 0x8263CB10
ExceptionCode: 0x3221225477 (The instruction at 0x%p referenced memory at 0x%p. The memory could not be %s.)
Last NTSTATUS: 0xC00000DD (An invalid parameter was passed to a service or function.)
Faulting thread name:

